# Tapping on Buttons over MapView is zooming the Map..?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode4.2, mkmapview

I have a MapView, Over which i have added a UIView (0, 216, 320, 200) contain 10 UIButtons. This UIView is to work like a menu, and Shows and Hides on a certain button action.

The problem here is, While the Menu is showing, when i tap a button single ime, it works perfectly, but tapping it very quickly multiple times makes the MapView Zoom(Which is under the UIView which contain the button). It means the touch event is passing to MapView.

Detail: Tapping on the button very quickly cause in MapView Zoom, and the Button Action performs when you stop tapping.

How can i prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is disable user interaction for the duration of your button's handler.  So in the selector do:

```
-(void)buttonSelector:(id)sender {
    _mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    // ... do what your button needs to do

    _mapView.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Of course, this assumes your button gets the event before the map view... which I think it should because it's on top of the map view.

To handle the rapid tapping, you could create a subclass of UIButton and use the following code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    _mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    _mapView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

In the builder change the class of the UIButton to your subclass.  If you debug the touch in the set passed to the `touchesEnd` method and look at the tapCount, you'll see all your taps have been caught here.

Comment: Yes, but doesnt work. The thing is, UIView is over MapView but still if tapping quickly, the MapView getting the Event First..

Comment: Ah yes, because it's picking it up as a double/multiple tap gesture.  So the normal gesture for actioning a button is a single tap - are you expecting the user to use rapid tapping to interact with your buttons, or is this an edge-case?

Comment: Its a case of QA send the app back to developer because of this issue.. :(

Comment: OK, I'll post another answer which might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so the problem was, I was adding UIView as subview over MapView.. I fixed it by adding the UIView as subview on self.view